# swiftで位置情報を毎秒取りたい！

Tags: swift

startUpdatingLocation()を使ってデリゲートで位置情報を取得しているのですが、毎秒取って来たいのに、10秒に一回くらいしか取れません。

そもそも取れないのでしょうか？
そうならば、なぜ取れないのでしょうか？
毎秒でなくても構わないので、数秒に一度でも取れないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

CLLocationManagerのdesiredAccuracyをkCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigationに設定すれば毎秒に近い頻度で位置情報を取得できるはず。